# How to move an image up in a div so that the top is cropped, not the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing an image that has been expanded to fit the entire page in width and most of the page in height.

```css
.mainarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sliderarea {
  border: 0px solid red;
  width: 605%;
  height: 80vh;
}

.slideimg {
  width: 16.5%;
  height: auto;
}

.imagetext {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainarea">
  <div class="layer"></div>

  <div class="imagetext">
    <h1>Slogan</h1>
    <button>Place An Order</button>
  </div>


  <div class="sliderarea">

    <img class="slideimg" id="pizza" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.64e63c78f7cf2b463e5b89e72162cfc2?rik=JartPjLCg6Q8%2bw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a series of images that are going to be sliding in from the side. Right now though I am primarily focused on the first image.
The problem is that by expanding the image, it scaled automatically so that the bottom of the image is now cropped. Is there a way for me to push it upwards so that the top is cropped/hidden, and I can see the bottom.
(I tried to use object-position: 0 -50%; but that did not work.)

Comment: Please show us the HTML and the related CSS - how are you sizing the img for example?

Comment: You want us to debug an issue with the image, while the code you supplied has no image in it.
Could you share the bit of the code that has the image?

Comment: Ok, I added in the image and the html. Basically when I expand that image to fit the div, I can only see half of the pizza. I would like to move it up.

Comment: @Jack pls edit ur html and css classes/ids their name doesn't match. you have two .mainarea in your css

Comment: @ArianShahalami thats my bad, i edited it and missed he's other class.

Comment: @Jack yet in your html an element with classname mainarea is mising

Comment: Yes, its missing quite a lot to be able to see what the issue is.

Comment: First of all I don't know what happened to the .mainarea part, I will add it back in. Second of all, I don't know how to show the project as all the images I am using are saved onto my computer and will not show up for you.

Comment: Ok, now I added in some more important stuff so you can see the way I have the background image with words and a button overlaying it. While this looks good here, on my own page the background image is cut off at the bottom. I am wondering how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.mainarea {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sliderarea {
    border: 0px solid red;
    width: 605%;
    height: 80vh;
}

.slideimg {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.imagetext {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainarea">
<div class="layer"></div>

<div class="sliderarea">

  <img class="slideimg" id="pizza" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.64e63c78f7cf2b463e5b89e72162cfc2?rik=JartPjLCg6Q8%2bw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0">
</div>

<div class="imagetext">
  <h1>Slogan</h1>
  <button>Place An Order</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks nice to me... maybe you would need to encrease the "bottom" property to crop a bit the bottom and show a bit more centered the image.
but for what you are trying to do, i think the only tip you need to take is to mess with the bottom property instead of top

Comment: im glad it was helpful! you can dive deeper on this at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could try `object-position: 0 -200px;`.

Here you are offsetting the Y position by negative 200 pixels.

For this solution you will need to adjust the offset for different resolutions by using media queries.

EDIT:
Another solution would be to swap out the image tags for background images and adjusting the `background-position` value, like so:

```css
.slideimg {
  background-image: url('https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.64e63c78f7cf2b463e5b89e72162cfc2?rik=JartPjLCg6Q8%2bw&pid=ImgRaw&r=0');
  height: 80vh;
  background-position: center center;
  /* possible values (x,y): center left right bottom top*/
}

.imagetext {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainarea">
  <div class="layer"></div>

  <div class="sliderarea">
    <div class="sliderarea">
      <div class="slideimg" id="pizza"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="imagetext">
      <h1>Slogan</h1>
      <button>Place An Order</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working on my browser Chromium 93

Comment: @ChiaraAni What specifically is not working? I just tried it on Chrome v96 and it works, same for FF. I don't have the Chromium browser installed to test it there.

Is there a specific style rule that isn't working or that needs prefixing?

Comment: The image is very big, and not right placed.